# EMR MapReduce Error: Java heap space

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-s3, emr

I read basically every post on SO but I still have memory issues. I use Airflow to instantiate my jobs on the EMR and everything worked fine till two days ago that every job was running out of memory. The jobs read from an S3 bucket and then I do some aggregation and then I save it back to S3.
I have two scheduled type of jobs - hourly and daily - in which I give different settings as shown below:

```
public static Configuration getJobConfiguration(String interval) {

    Configuration jobConfiguration = new Configuration();

    jobConfiguration.set("job.name", "JobImport Job");

    jobConfiguration.set("mr.mapreduce.framework.name", "yarn);

    jobConfiguration.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://xxxx:8020");
    jobConfiguration.set("dfs.client.use.datanode.hostname", "true");
    jobConfiguration.set("dfs.client.block.write.replace-datanode-on-failure.policy", "ALWAYS");
    jobConfiguration.set("dfs.client.block.write.replace-datanode-on-failure.best-effort", "true");

    if (interval.equals("hourly")) {
        jobConfiguration.set("mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize", "1000000");
        jobConfiguration.set("mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb", "6144"); // max memory for reducer
        jobConfiguration.set("mapreduce.map.memory.mb", "4098");    // max memory for mapper
        jobConfiguration.set("mapreduce.reduce.java.opts", "-Xmx4098m"); // reducer java heap
        jobConfiguration.set("mapreduce.map.java.opts", "-Xmx3075m");    // mapper java heap
    }
    else {
        jobConfiguration.set("mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize", "20000000");
        jobConfiguration.set("mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb", "8192"); // max memory for reducer
        jobConfiguration.set("mapreduce.map.memory.mb", "6144");    // max memory for mapper
        jobConfiguration.set("mapreduce.reduce.java.opts", "-Xmx6144m"); // reducer java heap
        jobConfiguration.set("mapreduce.map.java.opts", "-Xmx4098m");    // mapper java heap
    }

    return jobConfiguration;
}
```

My mapper and Reduce looks as follows:

```
private JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
private Text apiKeyText = new Text();
private Text eventsText = new Text();

@Override
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) {

    String line = value.toString();
    String[] hourlyEvents = line.split("\n");

    JsonElement elem;
    JsonObject ev;

    try {
        for (String events : hourlyEvents) {

            elem = this.parser.parse(events);
            ev = elem.getAsJsonObject();

            if(!ev.has("api_key") || !ev.has("events")) {
                continue;
            }

            this.apiKeyText.set(ev.get("api_key").getAsString());
            this.eventsText.set(ev.getAsJsonArray("events").toString());

            context.write(this.apiKeyText, this.eventsText);
        }
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}

// ------------------
// Separate class
// ------------------

private JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
private Text events = new Text();

@Override
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) {
    try {

        JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
        JsonArray dailyEvents = new JsonArray();

        for (Text eventsTmp : values) {
            JsonArray tmp = this.parser.parse(eventsTmp.toString()).getAsJsonArray();
            for (JsonElement ev: tmp) {
                dailyEvents.add(ev);
            }
        }

        obj.addProperty("api_key", key.toString());
        obj.add("events", dailyEvents);

        this.events.set(obj.toString());

        context.write(NullWritable.get(), this.events);
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

This is the dump after the mapreduce job:

`INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 56
    File System Counters
        FILE: Number of bytes read=40
        FILE: Number of bytes written=69703431
        FILE: Number of read operations=0
        FILE: Number of large read operations=0
        FILE: Number of write operations=0
        HDFS: Number of bytes read=3250
        HDFS: Number of bytes written=0
        HDFS: Number of read operations=58
        HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
        HDFS: Number of write operations=4
        S3N: Number of bytes read=501370932
        S3N: Number of bytes written=0
        S3N: Number of read operations=0
        S3N: Number of large read operations=0
        S3N: Number of write operations=0
    Job Counters
        Failed reduce tasks=4
        Killed reduce tasks=1
        Launched map tasks=26
        Launched reduce tasks=6
        Data-local map tasks=26
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=35841984
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=93264640
        Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=186677
        Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=364315
        Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=186677
        Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=364315
        Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=1146943488
        Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=2984468480
    Map-Reduce Framework
        Map input records=24
        Map output records=24
        Map output bytes=497227681
        Map output materialized bytes=66055825
        Input split bytes=3250
        Combine input records=0
        Combine output records=0
        Reduce input groups=0
        Reduce shuffle bytes=832
        Reduce input records=0
        Reduce output records=0
        Spilled Records=24
        Shuffled Maps =52
        Failed Shuffles=0
        Merged Map outputs=52
        GC time elapsed (ms)=23254
        CPU time spent (ms)=274180
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=25311526912
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=183834742784
        Total committed heap usage (bytes)=27816099840
    Shuffle Errors
        BAD_ID=0
        CONNECTION=0
        IO_ERROR=0
        WRONG_LENGTH=0
        WRONG_MAP=0
        WRONG_REDUCE=0
    File Input Format Counters
        Bytes Read=501370932
    File Output Format Counters
        Bytes Written=0`

The Cluster I am using is a `emr-5.2.0` with 2 nodes where each node is a **m3.xlarge** instance. To run the jar in the EMR I user `yarn jar ...` from the Steps (each step is instantiated from Airflow).

Besides those parameters in the configuration, I do not change anything else, so I use the default values. How can I solve the **Error: Java Heap Space** ?